# Using read -r within in-line shell scripting

Tags: linux, command-line, redhat-enterprise-linux, sh, read

I have a file that contains a list of absolute paths of several files.  I need to move all of the files listed in the file to another directory.  Unfortunately, I have to do this using in-line shell scripting (i.e. sh -c), and I have no power over text passed outside of the quotation marks of the script (I'm using a software that passes the command as an in-line shell script to the OS).

$file in the following command evaluates to an empty string when using in-line scripting.

`sh -c "while IFS= read -r file; do mv $file /target_dir; done < /source_dir/list_of_files.txt"`

But if I enter the command in the terminal, everything works fine:

`while IFS= read -r file; do mv "$file" /target_dir; done < /source_dir/list_of_files.txt`

Is it possible to use read in an in-line shell script? If so, what am I doing wrong?  I would like to avoid using bash file if possible, but I may not have that option.

OS:RedHat 8.7

list_of_files.txt

```
/home/usr1/file-16952.txt
/home/usr1/file-1825.txt
/home/usr1/file-2055.txt
/home/usr1/file-2165.txt
/home/usr1/file-2224.txt
/home/usr1/file-2452.txt
/home/usr1/file-4565.txt
/home/usr1/file-5763.txt
/home/usr1/file-8361.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `$file` variable you pass to `sh` is interpreted outside the `sh` context.
You should try to escape the dollar sign : `\$file`.
You can also add escaped quotes around `\"` to deal with filename containing spaces.

The final command would look like :

```shell
sh -c "while IFS= read -r file; do mv \"\$file\" /target_dir; done < /source_dir/list_of_files.txt"
```

Comment: ... which has the "same effect" as replacing the quotes from `"` to `'` (double to single), with the difference that any quotes _inside the string_ doesn't need to be escaped when using `'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ bash -c "while IFS= read -r file; do echo mv .$file. /target_dir; done < /source_dir/list_of_files.txt"
```

The `"`-quotes allows `$file` to be evaluated as you hit ENTER, taking the null or existing value in your CURRENT shell as literal text, replacing `$file` with either that value or `""` (the null string).

```
$ bash -c 'while IFS= read -r file; do echo mv "$file" /target_dir; done < "/source_dir/list_of_files.txt"'
```

Does not allow evaluation of `$variable` as you press ENTER, and thus leaves the TEXT `$file` as is, in place, until your one-liner is executing.

*I assume you have a reason to use `sh` - if not, beware that `sh` often is a link to `bash` or something else (making it mimick `sh`)*

Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ ls -l `which sh`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 mar 11  2021 /usr/bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: More on bash, www.tldp.org, Bash guides - old but still valid.

Comment: Unfortunately the use of sh is out of my control.  It's being called by the software I'm using :/.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The use of `sh` is up to each and everyone; just trying to tell that there might be one or two subtle or unexpected differences.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `read`, the problem is with your incorrect use of quotes around `$file`.

- In the working example, when you use `mv "$file" ...`, the variable inside double-quotes is expanded at the moment 'mv' is run.
- Very similarly, in the non-working example where you use `sh -c "... mv $file ..."`, the variable is expanded **at the moment 'sh' is run.** The resulting script is therefore not `mv $file /target_dir` but `mv  /target_dir`, with nothing left for expansion at that point.

To avoid this, either use single quotes for the parameter or use `\$` to prevent expansion:

- `sh -c '... mv $file ...'`
- `sh -c "... mv \$file ..."`

...and also bring back the double-quotes around `"$file"` *inside* the script – you still want to have them:

- `sh -c '... mv "$file" ...'`
- `sh -c "... mv \"\$file\" ..."`